# Postfix admin, POSTFIX, PHP, MYSQL, UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: php, mysql, admin, postfix-mta

I really need your help. I have ubuntu Linux version 18.04. And I install postfix. Postfix sending email (ok). Postfix admin creates emails accounts as it should (ok). And now the problem... If I send email to my email address I don't get any email. The folder is always empty. I really need your help. Where are these emails? Where is the path to them? How can I fix this?

Thank you,
Best regards,
Jure

Comment: Have you checked your SPAM folder?

Comment: Yes there is nothing...